# Run Function only once in Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Execute function only one time in Javascript, no matter how many times it has been called.
I write the following code, but does not working.

```
var counter = 0;

if(n.data === YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
  setTimeout(function() {                 
    if(counter===0) {
      r.frontPlayer.seekTo(10);
      counter++;
  }}, 2000);
}
```

Comment: For that specific function, you don't even need the counter. `setTimeout` will only run it once. If you're running this whole block of code multiple times, then that's a different problem.

Comment: It looks like `var counter = 0;` is in the same scope where `setTimeout` is declared

Comment: which function are you talking about? setTimeout callback function or r.frontPlayer.seekTo(10) ? setTimeout callback function will run only once unless the whole code block you wrote executes again.

Comment: if(n.data === YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
      r.frontPlayer.seekTo(10);
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not to use timeouts, they invite misery and suffering. This is a simple example, I use jquery for attaching the events but the function is independent of jquery. The key thing is using the object, the anonymous function in this case, to track state.

```
<button id="testButton">
test
</button>

$("#testButton").click(function() {
    if (null == this.ran) {
    console.log("do something");
    this.ran = true;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at underscore or lodash's [`_.once`](http://underscorejs.org/#once) function:

```
var fn = _.once(function() {
  console.log('this will only run once');
});
```

Or writing it yourself:

```
var fn = (function() {
  var called = false;
  var ret;

  return function() {
    if (called) return ret;
    called = true;
    // do stuff
    // .. 
    ret = 'some return value';
    return ret;
  };
})();
```

Comment: Really? You want him to use a library just for this...?

Comment: @Mikey Accidentally pressed submit before posting a "polyfill"